# GNU m4 macros auto generated file

Tags: latex, gnu, m4

I download latex package on which I want do some changes, but in this packege exist file include.m4 and I don't know what it does and how it was generated. Here its lines:

```
m4_changequote([[, ]])m4_dnl
m4_dnl
m4_define([[m4_FILE_INIT]], [[m4_dnl
%
% This is automaticaly generated file, do not edit it.
%
]])m4_dnl
m4_dnl
m4_define([[m4_FILE_ID]], [[m4_dnl
m4_patsubst([[$1]], [[\$Date::? \([0-9]+\)-\([0-9]+\)-\([0-9]+\).*]], [[\1/\2/\3]])m4_dnl
 v[[]]m4_ESKDX_VERSION]])m4_dnl
m4_dnl
m4_define([[m4_FILE_DATE]], [[m4_dnl
m4_patsubst([[$1]], [[\$Date::? \([0-9]+\)-\([0-9]+\)-\([0-9]+\).*]], [[\1/\2/\3]])]])m4_dnl
m4_dnl
```

Can you explain with which tool it was generated?

Thk. So this file is not autogenerated? ANd can you help me understand these lines from Makefile:

```
M4FLAGS = -P -Dm4_ESKDX_INIT="m4_include($(TOP_DIR)/include.m4)" \
  -Dm4_ESKDX_VERSION=$(VERSION) -Dm4_ESKDX_DATE=$(RELEASE_DATE)
```

And rule:

```
%.def: %.def.in $(M4DEPS)
    m4 $(M4FLAGS) $< >$@
%.sty: %.sty.in $(M4DEPS)
    m4 $(M4FLAGS) $< >$@
%.cls: %.cls.in $(M4DEPS)
    m4 $(M4FLAGS) $< >$@
```

As I can see GNU m4 options '-D' substitutes macro m4_ESKDX_INIT in .sty .cls files to m4_include(../include.m4) and then options '-P' first expands file include.m4 and furthemore expands macros in include.m4.

Comment: I've expanded my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a macro for the [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) macro processor. This file is designed to be used with the [`-P` or `--prefix-builtins`](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html#Operation-modes) commandline option. The `m4_` part will be stripped away when m4 evaluates this file. This file doesn't do anything itself, it just defines three macros (`FILE_INIT`, `FILE_ID` and `FILE_DATE`) which presumably will be used in another step. You might want to look in the other files for references to this one. The basic idea will be to load this file before running another file through m4 and it will replace those macros as it goes.

The message about automatically generated is supposed to end up in the final file as a comment. As we can see in the rules in the Makefile, each of the `.def`, `.sty` and `.cls` files are generated from an equivalently named `.in` file (so `result.cls` will be built from `result.cls.in`. by evaluating the macros in these files and replacing them with the equivalents.

So, to modify these files, you will want to edit the `.in` files.